# How to decide the direction of current in a LC circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

Suppose we have the following LC circuit set-up, where the current is assigned in the clock-wise direction:
[image]

Now, we would like to use KVL to obtain the proper differential equation:
$$L\frac{dI}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C} = 0$$

If we assign the voltage in accordance with the passive components rule, we have the following:
the left plate of the capacitor is negative, the right plate being positive.
The left end of the inductor is positive, with the right end being positive.

Now, this certainly gives us the correct equation using KVL.

But I was also considering to summing voltage from a physical perspective: if the current is running in the clockwise as shown, I naturally think that the left plate of the capacitor is positive, with the right plate negative. If we use KVL this way, we have this:
$$L\frac{dI}{dt} - \frac{Q}{C} = 0$$

I must have messed up somewhere, what am I doing wrong? I understand that $\frac{dI}{dt}$ is negative, but it is negative in both case, so I don't expect this to be the source of the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) which you have chosen to use is shown in the diagram below.

[image]

You have put labels on circuit element $X$.

The $i$ label with the arrow is the current label.
If the numerical value of $i$ is positive that means that current is flowing in the direction shown by the arrow.
If the numerical value of $i$ is negative that means that current is flowing in the opposite direction to that shown by the arrow.

The $v$ label with the plus and minus signs is the voltage label.
If the numerical value of $v$ is positive that means that the potential of the node labelled $+$ is greater than the potential of the node labelled $-$.
If the numerical value of $v$ is negative that means that the potential of the node labelled $+$ is less than than the potential of the node labelled $-$.

That is the convention and if you are using it you should stick to it and not let your intuition deviate from it.

If circuit element $X$ is a resistor then life is comparatively easy.
Current always flows from the node at a high potential through the resistor to the node at a lower potential.
You can therefore be certain that if the numerical value of $i$ is positive then the numerical value of $v$ will also be positive and on the other hand if the numerical value of $i$ is negative then the numerical value of $v$ will also be negative.

With capacitors and inductors that certainty is not there and this is where you have deviated from the correct application of the convention by stating

> if the current is running in the clockwise as shown, I naturally think that the left plate of the capacitor is positive, with the right plate negative.

The sign of the numerical value of the current does not determine the sign of the voltage as I will try and show below.

[image]

The left hand diagram can be interpreted as follows which is in fact what you have stated.
Node $D$ is at a higher potential than node $E$ as indicated by $v=+3$.
This means that the left hand plate of the capacitor has positive charge on it and the right hand plate has negative charge on it.
The current $i$, the flow of positive charges is such that the positive charge on the left hand plate is increasing and the negative charge on the right hand plate is increasing.
The capacitor is being charged.

The right hand diagram can be interpreted as follows which is contrary to what you have stated.
Node $G$ is at a higher potential than node $F$ as indicated by $v=-3$.
This means that the left hand plate of the capacitor has negative charge on it and the right hand plate has positive charge on it.
The current $i$, the flow of positive charges is such that the negative charge on the left hand plate is decreasing and the positive charge on the right hand plate is decreasing.
The capacitor is discharging.

---

Another thing which this convention can be used for is to determine the power, $vi$, related to the circuit element.
If the product $vi$ is positive the the circuit element is a consumer (sink) of electrical energy and in the case of a resistor that electrical energy is dissipated as heat which is always the case for a resistor.
If the product $vi$ is negative the the circuit element is a producer (source) of electrical energy.

For the capacitor on the right which is charging up the product $vi$ is positive and so it is a sink of electric energy storing it in its electric field.
For the capacitor on the left which is charging the product $vi=3\times 2 = +6$ is positive and so it is a sink of electric energy storing it in its electric field.

For the capacitor on the right which is discharging the product $vi= -3\times 2 = -6$ is negative and so it is a source of electric energy as the electric field between its plates decreases.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strictly wrong with choosing an arbitrary sign for $Q$, you just have to be clear on the relationship between $Q$ and $I$. You may find $I = -dQ/dt$ if you choose the two orientations to be opposite.

Right now the given arrow on the current $I$ describes a certain positive effect going clockwise around the circle. As we walk the circle clockwise we start off at some voltage $V$ and then we see an inductor, first. An inductor resists changes in current; if we were to increase the current coming into it, it would oppose that with an extra voltage on its distant side. So the voltage on the distant side must be $V + L~\dot I$ as we walk this circle; it must be a positive sign because that would create the higher voltage which resists the increase in current by trying to create a backflow.

After this, we do not see any junctions so we do not need to apply Kirchhoff's current laws, the full current $I$ goes into the next component.

Then as we walk the circuit further clockwise, we see a capacitor. A capacitor resists current-flow-at-all by building up a voltage against it. Again, for a positive current $I$ we expect the voltage on the left to be higher than the voltage on the right, so the voltage after this is $$V + L \frac{dI}{dt} + \frac1C\int_{-\infty}^t d\tau~I(\tau),$$and then we come back to the same place in the loop, so the resulting voltage must be $V$, which can only happen if 
$$L \frac{dI}{dt} + \frac1C\int_{-\infty}^t d\tau~I(\tau) = 0.$$
But, you are free to declare that you want to look at the capacitor “left-to-right” rather than the “right-to-left” that came with us naturally following the arrow of $I$ clockwise around the circle. If you do so, then you are simply defining that the way you are measuring the charge $Q$ on the capactor yields $$ Q = -\int_{-\infty}^td\tau~I(\tau).$$In such a case you do indeed have $L\dot I - Q/C = 0,$ which is totally fine, as long as you don't try to later state that $\dot Q = I(t)$ because that will cause the equations to say that $I = -I$ and conclude that $I=0.$

Answer (score 0):

> if the current is running in the clockwise as shown, I naturally think that the left plate of the capacitor is positive, with the right plate negative.

There's nothing that should make you think that.

If current is running clockwise, then the left plate is losing charge and its potential is becoming more negative (i.e. $\frac{dV_l}{dt}<0$, where $V_l$ is the voltage on the left plate). The direction of the current tells you nothing about the absolute value of the potential across the capacitor.

And, if you establish an oscillation in this circuit, 1/4 of the time you'll have the potential across the capacitor positive while it's becoming more negative, 1/4 of the time the potential will be positive while becoming more positive, 1/4 of the time the potential will be negative while becoming more negative, and 1/4 of the time the potential will be negative while becoming more positive.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, this certainly gives us the correct equation using KVL.

But is $L\frac{dI}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C} = 0$ **the** correct equation?

*The answer depends on the reference polarity one chooses for the voltages across the inductor and capacitor.*

To get started, recall that, by the [passive component rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) that you mention, the component's current reference direction is *into* the component's positively labelled terminal. It follows that $Q$ is the charge on the plate connected to the positively labelled terminal in order to satisfy

$$v_C = \frac{Q}{C}$$

Now, for concreteness, *choose* a reference polarity for the voltage across each component by placing a $+$ symbol on the left hand terminal of both the capacitor and inductor. Then, by the passive components rule, the reference direction for the capacitor current $i_C$ and inductor current $i_L$ is from left to right. KVL clockwise around the circuit then yields:

$$0 = v_L - v_C = L\frac{di_L}{dt} - \frac{Q}{C} = L\frac{di_L}{dt} - \frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^t\mathrm{d}\tau\,i_C(\tau)$$

Then, since $i_C = -I$,

$$L\frac{di_L}{dt} - \frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^t\mathrm{d}\tau\,i_C(\tau) = L\frac{dI}{dt} + \frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^t\mathrm{d}\tau\,I(\tau) = 0$$

But one could just as validly choose to place a $+$ symbol on the right terminal of the capacitor instead of the left terminal. KVL then yields:

$$0 = v_L + v'_C = L\frac{di_L}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C} = L\frac{di_L}{dt} + \frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^t\mathrm{d}\tau\,i_C(\tau)$$

where I've denoted with a prime the voltage across the capacitor with the reverse reference polarity from the previous choice. Carefully note that the equation in terms of $I$ is *unchanged by this reversal of reference polarity*.

In summary, the sign of the $\frac{Q}{C}$ term depends on the choice of the reference polarities. However, the equation in terms of the series current $I$ is independent of this choice (as it must be).